# iOS - Today extension widget cleared over time

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, today-extension, ios-app-group

## Situation as it should be

[image: Proper situation]

We have a today widget that shows a maximum of 6 buttons depending on data set in the corresponding app. This data is shared using app-groups. If at least one button is configured it will show up as shown in the image above. If the user is not logged in, or if no buttons are configured, it will show a message as shown in the image below.

[image: No buttons configured]

## Problem

After several hours (somewhere between 4 and 7) of not having opened the app, the widget reverts to the 'No buttons configured' view.

## Analysis so far

The way the data is loaded from the app-group is done using the code as shown below. ([gist for full code](https://gist.github.com/RomanovX/e4a1a0c3d76fd7ead473e1f453263ece)) In the way I had written it, the only way the 'No buttons configured' view can be shown is if the `buttons` array actually exists but has a length of zero.

I expected something like a cache clearing or a background service stopping, but as far as I can see, exceptions should be caught earlier:

- If no connection could be made to the app-group data, `userDefaults` should be nil, so it should show the 'Not logged in view'.
- In case the buttons were never defined, `buttons` should be nil and so again it should show the 'Not logged in view'

Considering the app does nothing in the background, the app itself could not be changing the buttons.

I tried reproducing this while having the debugger connected, but the problem will not reproduce.

Does anyone even have the slightest idea on how to fix this issue or how to start debugging this?

**Relevant files:**

- [TodayViewController](https://gist.github.com/RomanovX/e4a1a0c3d76fd7ead473e1f453263ece)
- [Cordova Plugin](https://gist.github.com/RomanovX/e8a49766fa935bff40bb6a7d20f75e80)

**Relevant code:**

```
private struct sharedData {
        static var baseUrl: String?
        static var token: String?
        static var phoneDeviceId: String?
        static var buttons: Array<Button>?
    }

func loadData() {
        let groupIdentifier = "group." + NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!
        var groupIdArray = groupIdentifier.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
        groupIdArray.removeAtIndex(groupIdArray.count - 1)
        let appGroupIdentifier = groupIdArray.joinWithSeparator(".");

        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.init(suiteName: appGroupIdentifier)
        if (userDefaults == nil) {
            print("Error in user defaults")
            setButtonTitle("Not logged in. Open Triggi to continue.")
            return false
        }
        sharedData.baseUrl = userDefaults?.valueForKey("baseUrl") as? String
        sharedData.token = userDefaults?.valueForKey("token") as? String
        sharedData.phoneDeviceId = userDefaults?.valueForKey("phoneDeviceId") as? String
        let buttons = userDefaults?.valueForKey("buttons") as? NSArray

        if (sharedData.baseUrl == nil || sharedData.token == nil || sharedData.phoneDeviceId == nil || buttons == nil) {
            print("Missing data")
            setButtonTitle("Not logged in. Open Triggi to continue.")
            return false
        }

        if (buttons?.count == 0) {
            print("No buttons configured")
            setButtonTitle("No buttons configured. Open Triggi to continue.")
            return false;
        }

    // More things are done with the data here
}
```

Comment: Is this in Swift 2???

Comment: Yes, sadly due to dependencies on third party plugins, we're still tied to Swift 2.3

Comment: Which plugins? Also, could you please provide the functions for `drawButton` and `colorFromName`?

Comment: Also, I think the issue lies in your app, where you set the "buttons" key in your user defaults.

Comment: The app is a cordova based app. The only swift based plugin is one for [geofencing](https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence) and that is simultaneously the only part f the app that does any background work. In order for the "buttons" key to be set, the app has to be actually opened, else that piece of code can never be run. 

Furthermore, the other two pieces of code (albeit I don't think they will provide any useful insight): [gist](https://gist.github.com/RomanovX/8dd95c919c625c9b9014752c3cc934fb)

Comment: First, you should not be using legacy Swift versions. Instead, find alternate plugins, or fork them and convert them yourself. In addition, could you please provide the code from your app (javascript or swift, whichever you are using) where you **set** the "buttons" of your `NSUserDefaults` suite?

Comment: I know, but currently there's not alternative plugin and we already have this plugin adapted to our purposes. Currently there is no one in our company adept enough at swift to properly convert the plugin. (if you know someone, let me know, we're willing to pay ^^') Anyhow, I've edited the question to contain more relevant files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146451/discussion-between-coder256-and-remy-kabel).

Answer (score 1):

`Today Extension Controller` is a `UIViewController` and thus follows the same lifecycle as that of a `UIViewController`. So, the lifecycle method `viewDidLoad()` is called everytime whenever the `widget` is loaded.

Also, `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler` is called:

1. when widget is updated in background
2. before widget snapshot is taken

So, instead of just calling `loadData()` in `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler`, also call it from `viewDidLoad()`.

Also, where have you written the code to add/remove `UIButtons` from superview and to show "No buttons configured" in your code?

Comment: I've added this as well as a number of logs for a more comprehensive debug. I'll set it running over time with a number of users. If it fixes it, I'll get back to you!